# Updating one RDBMS and NoSQL DBMS together

Tags: database, nosql, event-handling, microservices, rdbms

We have a use case in which we need to use a NoSQL database as a key value store and a RDBMS as a read view. We have an event driven system which will process the event only if the event id of the event is not found in the Key Value store. Once the event is processed, we need to add the event ID to the key value store and the result of the process to the RDBMS in one transaction.

Which combination of DBMS offers such solution? In summary, I would like to update a NoSQL and RDBMS together in one transaction with different data.